# CefSharp.WinForms Drag and Drop messageloop override

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, message-loop

I need to implement the answer provided to the following StackOverflow thread: 
[How to receive drag move and drag drop events using CefSharp winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711569/how-to-receive-drag-move-and-drag-drop-events-using-cefsharp-winforms?answertab=active#tab-top)

I've tried implementing the code, but I feel the answer provided does not give me enough detail about the code provided.

For instance, why does `IOleDropTarget` and `IOleDropTargetHelper` exist?

Why in the example usage of the `OleDragEnter` procedure, does it RaiseEvent to the Browsers DragEnter -- `RaiseEvent DBDragEnter(eff, New Point(winPT.x, winPT.y))`, when we removed it in the `EnumChildProc_Browser` -- `Dim ret = NativeMethodsEx.RevokeDragDrop(hwndChild)`

My implementation doesn't work because I receive an error when attempting to remove the drag and drop

You can find my code at my github repo : https://github.com/krptodr/StackOverflow.git

I expect to be able to see how to override the default DragHandler for cefSharp winForms, using the code provided from the above referenced solution.

Comment: @darbid would you be willing to assist?

Comment: Remove the `<ComImport>` attribute from your DragDropHelper class.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve that but I'm still having trouble getting a working solution.

Comment: @HansPassant My example is nearly working.  I can override the browsers Drag and Drop, but my new drag and drop handler is not grabbing the appropriate data for the IDataObject.